# KDE and Gnome option at Booting

Tags: 12.04, gnome, kde, desktop-environments

Can I have selection menu of KDE and Gnome at log-on enabling to select which environment I want to boot into in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run following command for installing KDE desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

after next login select KDE from "session" on the Login Prompt to start Desktop Environment (KDE).

[image]

See [this link](http://handytutorial.com/install-kde-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise/) for more detail.

Comment: Awesome!  Is there any way to make two entries, one for kdm and one for lightdm?

Comment: As far as know you can not do this because you can change display manager in another display manager. See this link: http://erl1.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or-kdm-in-ubuntu/